# Undesired flattening occuring

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery on exported GA data (see schema [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en))

Looking at the documentation, I see that when I selected a field that is inside a record it will automatically flatten that record and duplicate the surrounding columns.

So I tried to create a denormalized table that I could query in a more SQL like mindset

```
SELECT
  CONCAT( date, " ", if (hits.hour < 10,
      CONCAT("0", STRING(hits.hour)),
      STRING(hits.hour)), ":", IF(hits.minute < 10, CONCAT("0", STRING(hits.minute)), STRING(hits.minute)) ) AS hits.date__STRING,
  CONCAT(fullVisitorId, STRING(visitId)) AS session_id__STRING,
  fullVisitorId AS google_identity__STRING,
  MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=7, hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS customer_id__LONG,
  hits.hitNumber AS hit_number__INT,
  hits.type AS hit_type__STRING,
  hits.isInteraction AS hit_is_interaction__BOOLEAN,
  hits.isEntrance AS hit_is_entrance__BOOLEAN,
  hits.isExit AS hit_is_exit__BOOLEAN,
  hits.promotion.promoId AS promotion_id__STRING,
  hits.promotion.promoName AS promotion_name__STRING,
  hits.promotion.promoCreative AS promotion_creative__STRING,
  hits.promotion.promoPosition AS promotion_position__STRING,
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS event_category__STRING,
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction AS event_action__STRING,
  hits.eventInfo.eventLabel AS event_label__STRING,
  hits.eventInfo.eventValue AS event_value__INT,
  device.language AS device_language__STRING,
  device.screenResolution AS device_resolution__STRING,
  device.deviceCategory AS device_category__STRING,
  device.operatingSystem AS device_os__STRING,
  geoNetwork.country AS geo_country__STRING,
  geoNetwork.region AS geo_region__STRING,
  hits.page.searchKeyword AS hit_search_keyword__STRING,
  hits.page.searchCategory AS hits_search_category__STRING,
  hits.page.pageTitle AS hits_page_title__STRING,
  hits.page.pagePath AS page_path__STRING,
  hits.page.hostname AS page_hostname__STRING,
  hits.eCommerceAction.action_type AS commerce_action_type__INT,
  hits.eCommerceAction.step AS commerce_action_step__INT,
  hits.eCommerceAction.option AS commerce_action_option__STRING,
  hits.product.productSKU AS product_sku__STRING,
  hits.product.v2ProductName AS product_name__STRING,
  hits.product.productRevenue AS product_revenue__INT,
  hits.product.productPrice AS product_price__INT,
  hits.product.productQuantity AS product_quantity__INT,
  hits.product.productRefundAmount AS hits.product.product_refund_amount__INT,
  hits.product.v2ProductCategory AS product_category__STRING,
  hits.transaction.transactionId AS transaction_id__STRING,
  hits.transaction.transactionCoupon AS transaction_coupon__STRING,
  hits.transaction.transactionRevenue AS transaction_revenue__INT,
  hits.transaction.transactionTax AS transaction_tax__INT,
  hits.transaction.transactionShipping AS transaction_shipping__INT,
  hits.transaction.affiliation AS transaction_affiliation__STRING,
  hits.appInfo.screenName AS app_current_name__STRING,
  hits.appInfo.screenDepth AS app_screen_depth__INT,
  hits.appInfo.landingScreenName AS app_landing_screen__STRING,
  hits.appInfo.exitScreenName AS app_exit_screen__STRING,
  hits.exceptionInfo.description AS exception_description__STRING,
  hits.exceptionInfo.isFatal AS exception_is_fatal__BOOLEAN
FROM
  [98513938.ga_sessions_20151112]
 HAVING
  customer_id__LONG IS NOT NULL
  AND customer_id__LONG != 'NA'
  AND customer_id__LONG != ''
```

I wrote the result of this table into another table *denorm* (flatten on, large data set on).

I get different results when I query *denorm* with the clause

```
WHERE session_id_STRING = "100001897901013346771447300813"
```

versus wrapping the above query in (which yields desired results)

```
SELECT * FROM (_above query_) as foo where session_id_STRING = 100001897901013346771447300813
```

I'm sure this is by design, but if someone could explain the difference between these two methods that would be very helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are saying that you did check the box "Flatten Results" when you created the output table? And I assume from your question that session_id_STRING is a repeated field?

If those are correct assumptions, then what you are seeing is exactly the behavior you referenced from the documentation above. You asked BigQuery to "flatten results" so it turned your repeated field into an un-repeated field and duplicated all the fields around it so that you have a flat (i.e., no repeated data) table.

If the desired behavior is the one you see when querying over the subquery, then you should uncheck that box when creating your table.

Comment: sessionId is just `CONCAT(fullVisitorId, STRING(visitId)) AS session_id__STRING` , neither fullVisitor or visitId are repeated

Answer (score 0):

> Looking at the documentation, I see that when I selected a field that
>   is inside a record it will automatically flatten that record and
>   duplicate the surrounding columns.

This is not correct. BTW, can you please point to the documentation - it needs to be improved.

Selecting a field does not flatten that record. So if you have a table T with a single record {a = 1, b = (2, 2, 3)}, then do

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE b = 2
```

You still get a single record {a = 1, b = (2, 2)}. SELECT COUNT(a) from this subquery would return 1.

But once you write results of this query with flatten=on, you get two records: {a = 1, b = 2}, {a = 1, b = 2}. SELECT COUNT(a) from the flattened table would return 2.

Comment: Sorry, I mean when you encounter a repeated field `[]`, it's flattened how I described - not just nested objects `{}`.

Comment: In my reply, b is a repeated field, not nested. No flattening occurs in this SELECT statement you show. Flattening only occurs because you selected to write query result with flatten=on option. If the flattening is undesired, simply uncheck this option.